# GNU Parallel: limiting jobs does not work when using -n0 for constant/fixed parameters

Tags: multithreading, terminal, parallel-processing, limit, gnu-parallel

Here is what I am trying to achieve. I want to use GNU Parallel to run `nohup example.py fixedparam &` 10 times, but limiting it to 3 jobs. I want it to always be run with the exact same parameters, so I use `-N0`.

Currently, for testing, `example.py` is simply:

```
import os
import time

time.sleep(10)
```

Then here is how I am calling it with GNU Parallel:

```
seq 10 | parallel -j3 -N0 "nohup example.py &"
```

The problem is that the number of jobs ends up not being restricted to 3. As you can see by the partial screenshot I took from my terminal after calling `top`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as19g.png)

What am I doing wrong? How can I repeat in parallel the execution of `example.py` with fixed parameters using `-N0` but still limit the execution to a given number of jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found that the correct thing to do in my case is:

```
nohup seq 10 | parallel -j3 -N0 "python example.py" &
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove &:

```
seq 10 | parallel -j3 -N0 nohup example.py
```

Comment: I think the ideal would be to do what I just answered below, isn't it? I mean to put the "nohup" at the very beginning and the `&` at the very end. Or am I doing something fundamentally different there in my answer?